# How to create a time-limited notebook for take-home exams?

Tags: notebooks, education

I teach a physical sciences class using WL/Mathematica.  The students do homeworks where they develop code and create simulations and visualizations that focus on physical phenomena.  All that works well.

I'd like to try to give a take-home exam where students can do the same.  They would have unlimited resources (except other students) with a strict citation policy.

However, *my institution limits the time-length* of the exams we give.

I am looking for a *simple* way to determine when a student starts and stops work on the notebook.  It may be enough for the student to believe that I can determine their work times.

The exam would be available for download anytime during finals week, each student would be the 3 hours that suited them the best.

It need not be foolproof--I think almost any solution will have workarounds.

I just want to find minimal guardrails.

Ideas that come to mind (from complicated to simple)

1. Each student gets a personalized exam-notebook that they download from the cloud. That notebook would embed the student's name and download time.
2. Create a start button that uploads data to a DataBin and a stop button.
3. Analyze the CellChangeTimes when I collect the exams.
4. Ask the student to pledge that they have followed a set of rules.

Note: a rule at my institution is that we cannot grade on a curve. What we do is "look at the performance" and make a comparison to institutional advice (e.g., A "B" indicates that...)

Comment: If the time is limited to let's say 3 hours, you publish the exam at 9:00 and receive their solutions only until 12:00 ... ?

Comment: (1) Does your LMS have time-limited exams with file uploads? (2) If it's not a final exam, then consider calling it a paper or a project, which is how it sounds to me. I've never heard of an institution putting a time limit on a paper. The difference is that one may work on a paper several times over some relatively long period (days) and on a test only for one limited time interval.

Comment: @Domen  Ah, I left an important bit.  I want each student to pick the most convenient 3 hours for them during finals week.  That way, they can locally optimize their schedule.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Goofy, Yes, that would work, but my institution also has an arcane rule that any project/paper cannot be due during the finals period.  I think educators might benefit from having a simple system to give timed exams, but I am not sure